# Sum values in a dictionary based on condition that matches on keys in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Given a dictionary:

```
dic = {1: 45, 2: 4, 3: 56, 4: 667, 5: 90}
```

I would like to sum the values if their corresponding keys are greater than or equal to a threshold (say 3) and divide the sum by a number (say 100)

I tried the following:

```
threshold = 3
num_to_be_divided = 100
s = sum(v for v in dic.values() if dic.keys() > threshold)
prob = s / num_to_be_divided
```

Comment: `sum(v for v in dic.values() if v > threshold)/num_to_be_divided` or if you want to compare keys `sum(dic[k] for k in dic if k > threshold)/num_to_be_divided`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
print(sum(value for key, value in dic.items() if key >= threshold) / num_to_be_divided)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Sum values in a dictionary based on condition that match keys in Python

```
dic = {1: 45, 2: 4, 3: 56, 4: 667, 5: 90}
X = 3
_sum = sum(v for k,v in dic.items() if k >X)
print(_sum/100)
```